# Refreshing materialized view blocks an unrelated table

Tags: postgresql, locking, materialized-view, blocking

Last few days I was experiencing a problem that seems really strange to me and even though I have some experience with PostgreSQL, I really don't understand what may be the cause.

We have two services - A and B. The service A is running simple queries that look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_schema.table_a
WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2
```

Table A is 100% static and there are no DML operations running on it at all.

Service B is just refreshing a mat view concurrently like this:

```sql
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_schema.some_mat_view;
```

**The materialized view `some_mat_view` is not dependent on `table_a` neither directly, nor indirectly via some other views.**

However, from time to time, queries being executed by Service A seem to get locked for some time. I am running the following query to monitor locks:

```sql
  SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.database IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.database
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.granted
```

From time to time I am getting a result showing that a query executed by Service A is blocked by `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_schema.some_mat_view;` which is indeed being executed at the same time. However, as I mentioned, there are NO VISIBLE DEPENDENCIES between the view and the table. How is this sort of locking even possible? Does it have anything to do with how concurrent mat view refreshes are performed? Is it for example creating/dropping temp tables in the same schema under the hood, so the entire schema is locked for a short while and there are no queries possible against the schema at all?

Comment: To be clear, there's nothing in common between the two at all?...e.g. none of the tables inside the definition of the materialized view have a foreign key relationship between `table_a`? Perhaps the blocking is due to resource contention (and not locks)?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. The table depends only on the schema it belongs to, and the only objects related to the table itself are its constraints. It has no foreign keys. Can blocking of a particular query due to resource contention show the exact query that it's blocked by?

Comment: Ask your system.  The pg_locks table has columns which tell you what type of lock it is, and what specific object it is on.  Either add those columns to your join query, or just query pg_locks directly.

Comment: "*Can blocking of a particular query due to resource contention show the exact query that it's blocked by?*" - I'm not familiar enough with PostgreSQL to say if the catalog objects you're using can, but it's not impossible, generally speaking.